# How to verify that AWS lambda function is running on raspberry pi 3 for Greengrass?

Tags: aws-lambda, raspberry-pi3, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-analytics

I am preferring [official AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html) for AWS Greengrass setup in RaspberryPi3. I have already completed

[Module 1: Environment Setup for Greengrass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module1.html)

[Module 2: Installing the AWS IoT Greengrass Core Software](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module2.html)

When it comes to

[Module 3 (Part 1): Lambda Functions on AWS IoT Greengrass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module3-I.html)
, I got stucked in ["Verify the Lambda Function Is Running on the Core Device"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/lambda-check.html).

Because I can't see "hello world! Sent from greengrass core running on plateform: Linux - 4.19.86-v7+-armv7l-with-debian9.0" at MQTT client dashboard by subscribing to the topic "hello/world".

I have already deployed such deployment successfully for my greengrass group and provided subscriptions and Lambda functions as explained in AWS docs. I have also started Daemon on RaspberryPi3 by the command

`sudo ./greengrassd start`

at path location

```
/greengrass/ggc/core
```

I have also checked GGConnManager.log file present at path location

```
/greengrass/ggc/var/log/system
```

that shows such last log like,

```
[INFO]-MQTT server started.
```

But still didn't get any expected result at MQTT client dashboard.

Am I missing something ? How should I publish or subscribe to such topic for this task ?

OR Should I try any other method to verify this AWS lambda function ? Please help.

Comment: Hi @Ram Grandhi , thanks for ur help. I have tried 1 st thing, that is Good. But when I tried 2nd thing you have mentioned, I didn't get any directory named as "user' at /greengrass/ggc/var/log/ in my pi3. So now, what should be the issue with it. Should I try again from the beginning..?

Comment: Hi @ashwal -  

Couple of things to check then.   

a. check if lambdas are indeed OTA'ed to your device locally by listing under /greengrass/ggc/deployment/lambda/* .  
b. if you see your lambdas in there, then I doubt your greengrass Grouplevel settings in AWS Console is using CloudWatch Logs Only mechanism. Hence, you won't see anything created (like /user directory) on the device.   
c. Go to AWS console -> GGGroup --> Settings -> Enable local system logs for system & user lambdas. d. Finally, click on ''Deploy'' from AWS console.   

Let me know how it goes..   

cheers, ram

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `user` directory under the log directory, then that means that your user lambda function never executed. You probably need to set the function to be a pinned lambda, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/config-lambda.html section 7 for how to set that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to try out.

1. Go to AWS Console -> GGGroup ->  -> Settings -> Logs (make sure you select Local Logs for User Lambdas).
2. If you have done the rest correct, you should see lambda logs under /greengrass/ggc/var/log/user///*.log
3. For the sake of testing, you may want to add some console logs to your Lambdas (on module load, not on handler invocation).

cheers,
ram